# Zsh: command not found: snowpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, npm-install, web-development-server, snowpack

I am trying to create snowpack config file for my preact application. I have already installed all necessary libraries but it still show an error when I try to run this command `snowpack init`.  error `zsh: command not found: snowpack`

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "EF",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "snowpack dev --port 3000",
    "build": "snowpack build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prefresh/snowpack": "^3.1.2",
    "snowpack": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.5.15"
  }
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the snowpack binary isn't in your `$PATH`. The only time it should be is if you globally installed it. But because you haven't, you cannot access it.

There's an easy solution (and the correct way to run binaries) and that is using `npx` or `yarn`. Either will do the trick, so whichever you prefer.

`npx snowpack ...` or `yarn snowpack ...` from within your project will be able to access the snowpack binary and run it correctly.

Comment: I did npx snowpack. And it shows me list of snowpack commands, such as snowpack init, snopack dev. But when I try snowpack init, it shows me error: snowpack not found.  Problem is npx snowpack should create web modules directory. But it does not

Comment: You need to do `npx snowpack init`. That's what the `...` is for. Put in your subcommands there.